# marshal/unmarshal 2 different classes that are based on 2 different schemas

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb2

Im trying to configure a jaxb2Marshaller in spring beans config file but Im pretty new to Spring and JAXB so i might be going about it the wrong way.

What i want to achieve is the same bean that will marshal/unmarshal 2 different classes that are based on 2 different schemas. Perhaps thats not possible because when i have both configured and run my tests they fail for the second class in the configuration (AccountResponse).

This is the XML configuration:

```
<bean id="jaxb2Marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="marshallerProperties">
        <map>
            <entry key="com.sun.xml.bind.namespacePrefixMapper">
                <bean id="NamespacePrefixMapperImpl" class="org.lp.soa.controller.xml.LpsNamespacePrefixMapper" />
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>                              
            <value>org.lp.soa.controller.data.request.AccountRequest</value>
            <value>org.lp.soa.controller.data.response.AccountResponse</value>
        </list>
    </property>     
    <property name="schemas">
        <list>
        <value>classpath:schema/AccountRequest.xsd</value>
        <value>classpath:schema/AccountResponse.xsd</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

if i comment out the **AccountRequest.xsd** value from the config and then run my tests again the marshal/unmarshal for the second class (AccountResponse)  they all pass, if I then uncomment it I get the error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'accountResponse'.

Am i going about it the wrong way? Is it not supposed to be possible to handle two classes with two schemas?

Thanks,
Yoav.

Comment: Do you need JAXB? Don't use it. Use something like XStream which does not require configuration and will automatically marshal/unmarshal your business objects. Why spend *any* time doing this when you could be focusing on your app?

Comment: thanks! XStream looks interesting, ill give it a try.

Comment: i do want to validate the xml generated with the schemas ive defined, can XStream do that?

Comment: I didnt read your question clearly - I assumed each side was the same schema. Still, in general JAXB is a pain IMHO and I avoid it... actually, XStream will work with different schemas as long as they are compatible (i.e., if a new field is added on one side or the other, i think it'll still work gracefully, and there are 'converters' in xstream as well, .... I guess would need to know a bit more about your situation to recommend this approach... how many versions do you want to support, what's the difference, what's the main motivations etc.

Comment: Maybe I'm a heretic/ignorant, but I never ever use XML validation. Though I mostly use XML as a transport mechanism within closed door apps. I tend to write my own XML parsers and construct the POJOs myself, and fail with clear error messages which are often more descriptive than an XML validation failure would give.... nowadays, I write a Java API, provide it to the client and server, and they use XML and/or JSON only temporarily (for example, automatically marshalled/unmarshalled by JAX-RS)

Comment: thanks iangreen, XSTream is indeed very easy to use in my scenario. The only thing i havent been able to accomplish with it is forcing an exception when a required field is missing from the XML or null in the object im marshaling. Do you know if its possible? I cant find anything about it on Google or in the XSTream reference...

Answer (score 5):

> "
>   if i comment out the AccountRequest.xsd value from the config and then
>   run my tests again the marshal/unmarshal for the second class
>   (AccountResponse) they all pass, if I then uncomment it I get the
>   error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the
>   declaration of element 'accountResponse'.
>   "

Sounds like the Schema object being created by SchemaFactory.newSchema() is only processing the first xsd in the list.

If you have multiple schema files that are in the same namespace (targetNamespace?) then It could be this bug that is causing trouble:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XERCESJ-1130

What I did to work around this bug was creating a parent xsd file that included the other xsd files and then set the "schemaResourceResolver" property in the xml configuration with a LSResourceResolver implementation (See http://blog.frankel.ch/xml-validation-with-importedincluded-schemas for example)..

In your xml configuration add this:

parent.xsd file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns="http://www.yourdomain.com/FIXED/EXAMPLE"
           targetNamespace="http://www.yourdomain.com/FIXED/EXAMPLE"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           version="1.000"
           id="some_id">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="AccountRequest.xsd"/>
    <xs:include schemaLocation="AccountResponse.xsd"/>
</xs:schema>
```

In your xml configuration change the schemas property to:

```
<property name="schemas">
        <list>
        <value>classpath:schema/parent.xsd</value>
        </list>
</property>
```

Comment: Thanks, That technique was useful for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [MOXy](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/EclipseLink-OXM.XML). You could have a schema mapping defined by annotation, and the other mapping configured in a xml file.

As far as I know, XStream doesn't provide xml validations, so you could try to do a schema validation before unmarshal.
Using JAXB you could validate required elements/attributes using `@XmlElement/@XmlAttribute(required=true)` annotation.

Comment: +1 - Here is an example:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/09/mapping-objects-to-multiple-xml-schemas.html

Comment: thanks guys but not sure how these exactly are applicable to what im doing. Ive got spring doing all the wiring up of the Jaxb2Marshaller instance and im trying to map two different POJOs to two different schemas (one each). I want the same instance to be able to marshal/unmarshal either object/xml for both of them. Is Moxy still relevant? (im using NetBeans btw, dont know if that matters)...

Comment: spring's oxm supports different kinds of marshallers... use one that is easier/better than JAXB.. see my comment above.

Comment: XSTream is indeed very easy to use in my scenario. The only thing i havent been able to accomplish with it is forcing an exception when a required field is missing from the XML or null in the object im marshaling. Do you know if its possible?